# Synthese color for school activity

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm in school code, just start 3 month coding, 1st post on forum be kind^^!

I have a problem with the drag function.

I made an extracurricular activity for school kids. The idea is the synthese color but with a computer. i try to create one circle with drag function and around the circle they are a square border for resize function.

I focus on the Js function not really on css. The opacity made the synthese additive color system.

```js
let isResizing = false;
let isDragging = false;
let initialX, initialY, offsetX, offsetY, initialWidth, circle, square;

function startResize(evt) {
  isResizing = true;
  square = evt.target;
  circle = square.nextElementSibling;
  initialX = evt.clientX;
  initialY = evt.clientY;
  initialWidth = square.clientWidth;
}

function resizeCircle(evt) {
  if (!isResizing) return;
  const deltaX = evt.clientX - initialX;
  const deltaY = evt.clientY - initialY;
  const newWidth = initialWidth + deltaX;
  square.style.width = square.style.height = `${newWidth}px`;
  circle.style.width = circle.style.height = `${newWidth}px`;
}

function stopResize(evt) {
  isResizing = false;
}

function startDrag(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('circle') && circle.style.pointerEvents === 'visiblePainted') {
    isDragging = true;
    circle = evt.target;
    offsetX = evt.clientX - circle.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offsetY = evt.clientY - circle.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;


    circle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

    circle.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragCircle);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
  }
}

function dragCircle(evt) {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  circle.style.pointerEvents = 'visiblePainted';
  const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragCircle);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
} );
  evt.preventDefault();

  const x = evt.clientX - offsetX;
  const y = evt.clientY - offsetY;
  circle.parentElement.style.left = `${x}px`;
  circle.parentElement.style.top = `${y}px`;
}

function stopDrag(evt) {
  isDragging = false;}

const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener('mousedown', startResize);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', resizeCircle);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.sectionA {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  border: 2px rgb(167, 200, 204);
  flex: 7;
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 20px; /* Ajoutez un peu de marge intérieure si nécessaire */
}

.sectionB {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px rgb(167, 200, 204);
  flex: 3;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  padding: 20px; /* Ajoutez un peu de marge intérieure si nécessaire */
}
.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.nav-button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(207, 42, 88);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.homesearch{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.container {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
}

.circle {
  opacity: 0.45;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  pointer-events: visiblePainted;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
}

.square {
  width: 104px;
  height: 104px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed rgb(167, 200, 204);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="logo" href="#">Musiexplo</a>
  <div class="nav-buttons">
      <a class="nav-button" href="#">Connexion</a>
      <a class="nav-button" href="index.html">Nouvelle Recherche</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<body>
  <contain class="homesearch">
  <section class="sectionA row-col">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" >
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="sectionB row">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <label for="style1"  ></label>
    <input type="text" type="subimt">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Style1</button>
    
    <label for="style2"  ></label>
    <input type="text" type="subimt">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Style2</button>
  </form>
</section>
</contain>
```

I was inspired by draw.io to start the design . A square to resize and one "n/object" to drop.
i can resize but the drag function doesn't work.
I would like to understand what is wrong with Js.
See what mistakes I may have made in my logical reasoning
Thx everyone
Vibe

Answer (score -1):

Over all I want to say that your code looks very clean for being someone who is new to coding, nice job!

Minor thing: `<input type="text" type="subimt">` is not valid.  An input cannot have two types.  It's usually going to be `type="text"` because you want to be able to type in it.  However I know this is not what your question is about.

So see the below code. It's basically unchanged from your version except that I added `console.log` for each event so you can see when each event function is being called. It appears some are never being called properly, which is your problem.

```js
let isResizing = false;
let isDragging = false;
let initialX, initialY, offsetX, offsetY, initialWidth, circle, square;

function startResize(evt) {
  isResizing = true;
  console.log('startResize')
  square = evt.target;
  circle = square.nextElementSibling;
  initialX = evt.clientX;
  initialY = evt.clientY;
  initialWidth = square.clientWidth;
}

function resizeCircle(evt) {
  if (!isResizing) return;
  console.log('resizeCircle')
  const deltaX = evt.clientX - initialX;
  const deltaY = evt.clientY - initialY;
  const newWidth = initialWidth + deltaX;
  square.style.width = square.style.height = `${newWidth}px`;
  circle.style.width = circle.style.height = `${newWidth}px`;
}

function stopResize(evt) {
  isResizing = false;
  console.log('stopResize')
}

function startDrag(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('circle') && circle.style.pointerEvents === 'visiblePainted') {
    isDragging = true;
    console.log('startDrag')
    circle = evt.target;
    offsetX = evt.clientX - circle.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offsetY = evt.clientY - circle.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    circle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

    circle.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragCircle);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
  }
}

function dragCircle(evt) {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  console.log('dragCircle')
  circle.style.pointerEvents = 'visiblePainted';
  const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
  circles.forEach(circle => {
    circle.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragCircle);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
  });
  evt.preventDefault();

  const x = evt.clientX - offsetX;
  const y = evt.clientY - offsetY;
  circle.parentElement.style.left = `${x}px`;
  circle.parentElement.style.top = `${y}px`;
}

function stopDrag(evt) {
  isDragging = false;
  console.log('stopDrag')
}

const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener('mousedown', startResize);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', resizeCircle);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.sectionA {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  border: 2px rgb(167, 200, 204);
  flex: 7;
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 20px; /* Ajoutez un peu de marge intérieure si nécessaire */
}

.sectionB {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px rgb(167, 200, 204);
  flex: 3;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  padding: 20px; /* Ajoutez un peu de marge intérieure si nécessaire */
}
.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.nav-button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(207, 42, 88);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.homesearch{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.container {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
}

.circle {
  opacity: 0.45;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  pointer-events: visiblePainted;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
}

.square {
  width: 104px;
  height: 104px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed rgb(167, 200, 204);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="logo" href="#">Musiexplo</a>
  <div class="nav-buttons">
      <a class="nav-button" href="#">Connexion</a>
      <a class="nav-button" href="index.html">Nouvelle Recherche</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<body>
  <contain class="homesearch">
  <section class="sectionA row-col">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" >
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="sectionB row">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <label for="style1"  ></label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Style1</button>
    
    <label for="style2"  ></label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Style2</button>
  </form>
</section>
</contain>
```

I believe this is happening because you are doing a lot of `addEventListener` and then `removeEventListener` - you should just add the listeners once and then decide when to pay attention to them and probably not remove the listeners.

I do not have the time to edit and debug this code right now, but I suggest that you modify it in the following ways:

- Attach all `document` event listeners **once** outside of a function call
- Do not remove these listeners, but add boolean flags inside of them to determine when you should or should not do anything (you are already doing this a bit)
- Add the event listeners on elements like the `circle` once, and again do not remove them.

Adding/removing listeners is just too complex an unneeded for this. This will greatly simplify your code and make it easier to understand as well.

Comment: Hi, Chris Thank you for our teacher, is really epic. I'm not yet the reflex to use var_dump() echo () or consol.log to control events. Anyway, thank you, I'll take your advice further.